# Can I invoke a client´s method from a server with RMI

Tags: java, architecture, websocket, jms, rmi

I would like to know if with RMI a server can remotely invoke a method from any of his clients, or just the clients can do this with their server.

Comment: If you tried maybe. But usually server only answer to his clients, not wice wersa.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan In other words you don't know the answer. Your comment isn't much help.

Comment: @EJP at first i want to show him/her that this approach is not normal in much cases. If he/she will describe real necessity of that approach, I would provide more detailed description.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan More detailed than 'maybe'? If you don't know the answer you should say so or probably just not comment. You don't need the OP's motivation to post the answer, if you know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, firewalls permitting. The client has to export its callbacks as remote objects and supply them to the server, typically via some `registerCallback()` API. Then the server just calls the methods.

However firewalls to the Internet typically *don't* permit callbacks, and if they do there may be issues with port numbers: you will probably need the clients to export their remote objects on a specific port which is opened in the firewall, typically 1099.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of any implications of such a design decision, it is possible to use RMI between two JVMs that are accessible through the network. This means that if the server can access its clients through the network, and the clients have a JVM available and can act as RMI servers, then it is possible to make a client or each of the clients an RMI server and have the "server" communicate with each one of them.

Assuming the server is an application server i advise you to use the Java Messaging Service (JMS) to allow the server communicate with the client systems.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the solution provided by melc, it is also possible to achieve a full duplex communication between the client and server by using WebSockets. They are now part of the Java EE 7 specification, you can read something more about them here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm. There are also other solutions, like Comet, or JMS (which is used like webosckets in RichFaces).

Comment: So it is not possible but are other ways of do that, and RMI is just for server hard work, thanks

Comment: @Canes5 It *is* possible, and there is nothing in this answer or indeed this entire page that says otherwise.

Comment: Link is dead. Maybe https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm now?